# "Start something January first" or "start something on January first"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please if the preposition *on* is optional in the following sentence.

> I will take up going to the jym (**on**) January first.

I have heard a native English speaker say it without an *on*. Is that a mistake or just a conversational way of speaking. Can I drop *on* in formal writting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Over time, people seem to have got too busy to say dates properly, and start cutting filler words out. Different locales tend to say dates in different orders, so US English tends to say "January first" , whereas traditional UK English would say "first of January". (in the UK though, dates are being americanised to some extents, so we're saying dates in the wrong order)

The "on" I think stems more from the UK format (could be wrong) , where the full sentence would be "the event happened on the first of January", which by stripping words out and rearranging could turn to "the event happened January first" instead. The most significant part of the change was americanising the date, but also the omission of the "on" made the sentence shorter.

The sentence works absolutely fine both ways, but you could say without "on" could be considered the "lazy" or "nontraditional" way of saying it.